# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h error for json option passed as param to a function

Tags: javascript, json

JSON Array:

```
 var data= '[{"id":"1","text":"B.Sc"},{"id":"2","text":"M.Pharm"},{"id":"3","text":"M.Tech"},{"id":"4","text":"BBM"},{"id":"6","text":"MCA"},{"id":"10","text":"PGDMA"},{"id":"11","text":"Diploma"},{"id":"12","text":"Plus Two"},{"id":"14","text":"fdf"},{"id":"15","text":"dfdf"},{"id":"16","text":"alert("hi");"},{"id":"1235","text":"B.Tech"},{"id":"10001","text":"MBA"}]';
selectParams['data'] =  jQuery.parseJSON(data); // errors happens here
```

I tried in http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ and its throwing error as well.

The problem is with ("") double quotes within the JSON array.

I tried several options but nothing works. How can we parse JSON array with this structure like having double quotes and single quotes as values.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where did the JSON come from? All JSON libraries should do this right, don't try to create JSON by hand.

Answer (score 1):

When generating JSON string, escape all keys and values

```
val.replace('"', '\"'); //json_encode($fullArray); in PHP will escape automatically.
```

so that `"alert("hi");"` becomes `"alert(\"hi\")"`

Comment: can i do the same for entire array rather than that value.

Comment: was using JSON.stringify and realized later it didn't automatically escape the quotes

Answer (score 1):

Escape your inner double quotes:

```
alert(\"hi\")
```